Conditional Dropdowns in Google Sheets Based on Multiple Criteria
I’m having trouble setting up conditional drop-downs in Google Sheets based on specific criteria. Here’s what I’m trying to achieve and the issues I’ve encountered:
Objective
I want to create a drop-down list in a column if the following conditions are met:
- Condition 01: The value in column E of the same row should be one of these specified values:
T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, P1, P2, P3, B1, or B2.
- Condition 2:
The drop-down options should be sourced from the sheet 'SEO Validación Datos'. Specifically, the data should come from the column starting at row 6 in 'SEO Validación Datos', but only if the value in row 2 of that sheet is "HOME".
To finish off, I would like to use conditional formatting to show the drop-down options in Red if the value in column C in sheet 'SEO' equals Principal and Blue if the value equals Secundaria. There might be some changes required in the SEO Validación sheet, but I don't know how to progress at this point.

Attempts Made
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KIgP7u9yS_w3DjBnXwHUkHuqLaR9zmdlaRbbOWt1q3I/edit?usp=sharing

Data Validation Setup
I attempted to use the Data Validation feature to create drop-downs based on the values the sheet 'SEO Validación Datos'. I was able to set up drop-downs but:

I could not link the drop-down list dynamically based on the conditions from column E. When I try to add the second rule the first one disappears altogether.
I was also unable to create a condition for the value 'Home' row 2 of the sheet 'SEO Validación Datos'

Using Formula to Display Values
I tried using the formula
=IF(OR(E3="T1", E3="T2", E3="T3", E3="T4", E3="T5", E3="T6", E3="P1", E3="P2", E3="P3", E3="B1", E3="B2"), G3, "")
in a helper column to display values conditionally.
However, this approach only displays values and does not apply drop-down functionality.
Dynamic Dropdown Application
I tried combining REGEXMATCH with other formulas to conditionally show drop-down options but faced difficulties getting the drop-down to appear based on dynamic conditions.
Request
Can anyone provide a solution or guide on how to achieve this in Google Sheets?
Under the sheet 'Ideal result - Home' there is a preview of what I am hoping to achieve.


I think, what you are looking for is something called Dynamic Drop-down. This is currently widely answered in Stack overflow. Based on the previous answers I have encountered on Stack overflow. This is doable using apps script, would you be open on getting answers using Google Apps Script.

Hey @Patsytalk, sure Google App Script would be an option for me. I have tried different approaches but none of them has yielded the result I am looking for. Happy to get an answer in any direction really. Thanks!

This question is too broad. Please focus it one specific problem. You can post another question to ask about tanother specific problem.

Creating Dynamic Dropdowns Referencing values from other Sheets
It seems that there are some issues with getting the correct ranges. So for this one I would suggest that you delete currently existing Data Validation on the Sheet Range you are trying to work with to avoid overlapping over validation.
Sample Code:
function applyDropdown(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var homeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Expected Result - Home")
var vsSheetData = ss.getSheetByName("Validación Scripts").getRange("A4:A8");
var columnH = homeSheet.getRange(4,5,homeSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
var columnHValues = columnH.getValues().flat();
var validValues = ['T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'B1', 'B2']
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(vsSheetData).build();
for(x = 0; x <columnHValues.length; x++){
if(columnHValues[x] != "" && validValues.includes(columnHValues[x])){
  homeSheet.getRange(x+4, 8).setDataValidation(rule);
  }

}

}

Sample Output:

Reference:
Data Validation

Thank you I see now where the error is. This is very useful!
